# Creating Python venv for running a dash application on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, operating-systems, virtualenv, dash

I am trying to create a Python [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to include packages like [dash](https://plot.ly/products/dash/) so I can deploy a dash application on [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/).

I was unable to follow the PythonAnywhere instructions for creating a virtual Python environment because I would run out of disk space during `pip install dash`.

I am using a Windows laptop and PythonAnywhere provides me with a Unix system to deploy my applications with. If I create a venv with my Windows system, would that work in the Unix system provided by PythonAnywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Virtual environments in Python work within the scope of the OS. When you create a new virtual environment with e.g.`venv`, you are essentially copying your current (existing) Python installation to a new, isolated directory. That's it. Virtual environments do not ensure cross-platform compatibility (e.g. Windows to Unix).

It's up to you to ensure that your scripts, applications and modules are compatible with your target OS. Many Python modules can be used on any platform supported by Python (though not all).

Dash itself seems to have no requirements regarding OS and apparently uses other OS-agnostic software. So the chances are good that any Dash app you create on Windows will likely run on PythonAnywhere, regardless of whether or not you create any kind of virtual environment on your laptop.

---

*To be clear, you upload your Python code to PythonAnywhere, not your entire Windows Python installation (or virtual environment).*

---